# How to implement in-built scheduled celery tasks in third party packages

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

I have looked at the [celery codebase](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/06390779a0d04b494c65462208e24f8cd4475571/celery/app/builtins.py#L21) to get an idea of implementing an in-built scheduled task but I am not sure whether that's the way to go about it for my case.

I have a third-party package (meant to be used in Django projects) that needs to have a scheduled in-built celery task, just as `backend_cleanup` is built in celery.

The developer using the package needs to be able to disable the task or update the crontab schedule using some Django settings.

This is what I have so far in the package code based on what I saw in the [docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries):

```
# tasks.py
app = Celery()

@shared_task
def do_stuff():
    # do some stuff that will access the database
    pass

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    okay_to_run = getattr(settings, 'OKAY_TO_RUN', False)

    if okay_to_run:
        default_schedule = crontab(0, 0, day_of_month='2')
        schedule = getattr(settings, 'OKAY_TO_RUN_SCHEDULE', None)

        if schedule is None:
            sender.add_periodic_task(default_schedule, do_stuff.s())
        else:
            sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(**schedule), do_stuff.s())
```

I see celery detects the task but it does not schedule it. What could be wrong and is there a better approach to this?

**UPDATE**

I was probably overthinking this. I have just made the task a normal `shared_task` and left the scheduling for the developer who will be re-using the app.